# Acumatica customization changing custom field control type

Tags: acumatica

How can i change the Type of the Custom field in Acumatica customization project? I created a new custom field of "TextEdit" via acumatica gui. Now i would like to change its type to "ComboBox".

I've changed it but after publish the customization project custom field still is TextEdit.

Comment: "I've changed it", how? If you have done the change in the code with correct string list, Did you delete and add the control back to UI

Comment: I've changed it from gui . As I guess changing control type from gui not works.  Changing from code make it works, but in gui it still is TextEdit. I think it's a bug of acumatica framework. In gui I mean Layout Editor for customization project

Comment: just change the value in your customization project and save to database. You can do this by clicking edit XML or export the zip, unzip and change the project.xml. The import back in and publish. I typically do most changes directly in the project.xml vs the UI

Answer (score 0):

When you add the control to the UI using the customization, select the control as combo box.

[image]